# In a Power BI card can I display title right above data label?

Tags: sql-server, data-visualization, powerbi

How can I put title on a label in power BI desktop?
Something like on a picture below:

[image]

Alignment for title only can be on a left, right or centered.

[image]

Reducing the card size will reduce the whole box itself:

[image]

I'm just trying to to the same report as here:
https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMjc2NzExODItMjNhYy00ZWMxLWI2NGItYjFiNWMzYzUzMzhlIiwidCI6IjU3NGMzZTU2LTQ5MjQtNDAwNC1hZDFhLWQ4NDI3ZTdkYjI0MSIsImMiOjZ9

And want to make sure I not missing anything.

Comment: hide the label on the card and use a seperate text box

Comment: Or you can just reduce the card size.

Comment: Reducing card size will reduce the total size of the box. I am just trying to copy the example from powerBI website (Edited above). So I just want to make sure I am not mission simple tricks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Observations**

This is indeed achieved by having a smaller `Card` in front of a bigger black `Rectangle`.

You can see that the `Focus mode` button is near in the middle, rather than in the upper right hand corner as other visuals, which suggests the size of the actual visual.

[image: focus mode 1]
[image: focus mode 2]

Using [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/), you can see that it consists of a `rect svg` in a div with class `visual-basicShape`. While the inner one is a smaller svg with class `card` in a div with `visual-card` class.

[image: rect]
[image: card]

---

**Solutions**

So in Power BI, you can achieve so by inserting a rectangle with line and fill color set to black.

[image: power bi rectangle]

And then add a smaller card visual with data label and title set to white.

[image: power bi card]

Make sure to send to back the rectangle element.

[image: send to back]

---

**Results**

[image: results]

Comment: Foxan Ng
Thank  you, amazing answer, like always!